# How can I set multiple environment variables at once

Tags: 20.04, environment-variables

Is it possible to define multiple environment variables at once? Ideally I'd like to paste them all at once instead of setting each one separately.

Comment: Where are you setting these each separately?

Comment: Please explain your problem. How are you setting them separately ? And where ?

Answer (score 2):

Simply, `export a="1" b="2" c="...`, etc.

Is this really what you want to do?

Perhaps you want to put them in, `.bashrc`?

https://www.routerhosting.com/knowledge-base/what-is-linux-bashrc-and-how-to-use-it-full-guide/